# concatenate a string into a file through a command that is a single valued argument to a script

Tags: bash

I need to concatenate a string into a file through a command that is a single valued argument to a script:

defining sample text:
`TEXT="sample text"`

defining characteristic script : `transfer.sh
$1`

desired usage (to be corrected):
`./transfer.sh "echo $TEXT >> test.log"`

desired output in test.log
... `(previous contents)
sample text`

Comment: Do you mean append "sample text" to every line? Or at the end of the last line? Or as a new line after the last line? Does it matter whether the last line already has a line terminator? I think you will find answers to all of these in Google as soon as you manage to formulate the problem in well-recognized terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` command in your `transfer.sh` file:

```
eval $1
```

It will generate `test.log` with "sample text" in the last line. Be aware that anything you pass to `transfer.sh` script will be executed. So, if your user passes `"rm -r /home/alan/papers"`, everything in your `papers` folder will be deleted.